# Google Apps Script - Can you get the condition for an IF statement from a cell or just a predefined text string?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can the conditions for an if statement be gotten from say a cell value, rather than having to add it into the code, so that I can just have a table of the markers and the conditions on which the markers are based?

What I mean:

| Name | Sale |
| --- | --- |
| Farhan Simon | 1060 |
| Sion Dawe | 1356 |
| Danyal Sweeney | 1591 |
| Kirandeep Beck | 1662 |
| Debbie Woolley | 1972 |

```
Instead of :
for (var i=1;i<table.length;i++{
if(table[i][1]>1500){
Logger.log(table[i]);
}};
```

Can I use something like:

```
var condition = 'table[i][1]>1500';
for (var i=1;i<table.length;i++{
if(condition){
Logger.log(table[i]);
}};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IF formula in google sheets inside each cell to check, so that it returns true or false. At that point from Apps Script you can loop directly on those values.